# How to extract div having no class using jsoup?

Tags: scala, jsoup, html-parsing

How to extract each fields? I am not able to get the div without any class, the div having class also comes along .

```
<div class="donut-text d-lg-table-cell pt-sm pt-lg-0 pl-lg-sm">
 <div>David M. XYZ</div>
 <div class="numCEORatings">194 Ratings</div>
</div>
```

```
val field = Doc.select("div.donut-text.d-lg-table-cell.pt-sm.pt-lg-0.pl-lg-sm")
println(field.text())

//This gives both>> David M. XYZ 194 Ratings
//How to extract each
```

Answer (score 1):

Your current selector targets the outermost div. So when you call `.text`, you get the concatenated contents of the outer div, with HTML markup removed.

To select the inner items, append `*` to your current selector.

```
val html =
  """
      <div class="donut-text d-lg-table-cell pt-sm pt-lg-0 pl-lg-sm">
        <div>David M. XYZ</div>
        <div class="numCEORatings">194 Ratings</div>
      </div>
  """

val Doc: Document = Jsoup.parse(html)
val elements: Elements = 
  Doc.select("div.donut-text.d-lg-table-cell.pt-sm.pt-lg-0.pl-lg-sm *")

elements.toArray.foreach { el =>
  println(el)
}
```

If you just want to exclude the second div from the selection, you can use a `:not` CSS selector:

```
Doc.select("div.donut-text.d-lg-table-cell.pt-sm.pt-lg-0.pl-lg-sm *:not(.numCEORatings)")
```